# How to share java script methods between html and svg?

Tags: html, svg, internet-explorer-9

I have got a html page embedded with a .svg. I have written most of the logic in java script and would like to share the same .js between html and .svg file:

for ex: I have got the following in mylogic.js:

```
var xmlDoc = null;
function loadXmlDoc() {
   xmlDoc = new XmlDoc.....
}

function onHtmlLoad() {
   loadXmlDoc();
}

function onSvgLoad() {
   xmlDoc.getElemementById(...
}`
```

and in the Html, I have got

```
<html>
<script src="mylogic.js"></script>
<body onLoad='onHtmlLoad();">
...
<object id='svgid' data='sample.svg'.../>
...
</body>
</html>
```

and the java script included in the html page is not visible in the embedded .svg file so I have to include them again like...

```
<svg...onload="window.onSvgLoad();">
<script xlink:href="mylogic.js></script>
</svg>
```

since I included the .js file twice, I am getting the xmlDoc as null inside onSvgLoad() function. I believe, there should be a way to get the same instance of xmlDoc loaded from html in svg. but I am not getting it..?

alternatively I tried not to include .js file in svg instead tried changing onload to onload="window.top.onSvgLoad();" ; then to onload="window.parent.onSvgLoad();" but still did not work! 
*Please note that I am using IE9 with its native support for Html5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript included in the html page IS visible from the embedded .svg file. Remove the `script` tag from the embedded svg and call the methods you want as parent.method e.g. if mylogic.js had

```
function hello()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

you could write

```
<script>
  alert(parent.hello());
</script>
```

in the embedded .svg file to call it.

Comment: mmm...it works only in IE9 Standard doc mode, not in Quirks mode! :(

Comment: SVG doesn't work at all in IE9 Quirks mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx